# is the "char *" type an address?

Tags: c, pointers

I know that:

```
char * pword;
```

declares a table which first element is used as a pointer.
And

```
*pword <=> * (&pword[0]) <=> pword[0]
```

(Tell me if I'm wrong.)

But what I want to know is if `char*` is a type (as `int` is for integers) and if yes does it represents an address?

Comment: `char * pword` declares `pword` to be a pointer to a `char`. It does not declare a `char` nor a table to `char`, but just the address of a `char`. `pword` could be set to point to a `char` or an array of `char` declared elsewhere.

Comment: You left out one: `*pword <==> pword[0] <==> *(pword + 0)` as well. This may not seem important, but it is very much so with `pword[n]  <==> *(pword + n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `char*` is a type, and a variable of that type represents a memory address for a `char`-type variable (formally a "pointer to char"). The [C data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Pointer_types) article on Wikipedia is a good introduction of the various types.

Comment: More to the point, `char * pword;` declares a *variable* that can hold a memory address of a `char`. The understanding and grasping of the word *variable* is critical.

Answer (score 0):

```
*pword <=> * (&pword[0]) <=> pword[0]
```

you are correct here.

C provides the `char` type variable, in your case `pword` is a pointer to `char` type.
Also, a character string is stored in an array of character type, one ASCII character per location.